# Why is Cod::Blocks giving me Null instead of a input char?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, output, codeblocks

**Source Code:**

#3 main.c

```
# include "func.h"

int main(void) {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

#3 func.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputName();
void printName();
void func();
```

#3 func.c

```
#include "func.h"

char GLOBAL_NAME;

void inputName() {
    scanf("%s", &GLOBAL_NAME);
}

void printName() {
    printf("Your name is: %s.\n", &GLOBAL_NAME);
}

void func(void) {
    inputName();
    printName();
}
```

**Out Put:**

```
Your name is: (null).
```

I used https://www.online-cpp.com/online_c_compiler with the same code, it works fine on the online compiler. but when I try to use it on Code::Blocks it shows me:

```
Your name is: (null).
```

Don't know what's the problem, Could it be a compiler thing?

I'm using a windows machine for Code::Blocks using GCC I think as the compiler.

Comment: found what was wrong, it needed to be re-debugged first before compiling it again. 
I hate using Code::Blocks :(

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your char variable with a length and since you have not initialized it with a length it returns NULL.

```
char GLOBAL_NAME[30];
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, still giving me null. The program is suppose to take input from the user: a name, then print that name on the screen next to "your name is:". it works fine on the online compiler with or with out the length being initialized.

Comment: Did you try to update your scanf to canf("%s", GLOBAL_NAME);

Comment: still prints "Your name is: (null)" first then the input*.

*As in being able to input the name, before the printed text